# Given $g(1) = 6$, $g'(1) = -1$, find $d/dx(2 g(x)/(x^2 + 1))$ when $x = 1$

Tags: calculus

Why is the answer $-7$? I plugged $1$ into the equation and I ended up with $12/2$ and got $6$. Can someone explain to me what I did wrong?

Comment: We can't tell what you did wrong unless you show us how you got your answer.

Comment: I told you, I plugged 1 into the equation so I had (2*g(1)/1^2 + 1). This gave me 12/2, which I divided to get 6.

Comment: You have to take the indicated derivative first.  You ignored the $d/dx$ part

Comment: It looks as if you got $6$ by ignoring $d/dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying Quotient Rule, we find that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{2g(x)}{x^2+1} \right]
&= \frac{(x^2+1)\frac{d}{dx}[2g(x)] - 2g(x)\frac{d}{dx}[x^2+1]}{(x^2+1)^2} \\
&= \frac{(x^2+1)[2g'(x)] - 2g(x)[2x]}{(x^2+1)^2} \\
&= \frac{2(x^2+1)g'(x) - 4xg(x)}{(x^2+1)^2} \\
\end{align*}
Hence, substituting $x = 1$, we obtain:
$$
\frac{2(1^2+1)g'(1) - 4(1)g(1)}{(1^2+1)^2}
= \frac{4(-1) - 4(6)}{4}
= -1 - 6 = -7
$$

Comment: I don't understand how you took the derivative of the function with the quotient rule. What happened to the derivative of 2g(x) and the derivative of x^2 + 1? Can you break down the derivative process a little bit more please?

Comment: I added an extra step; does that help?

Comment: Yup, that's perfect. Thank you!!! I get it now!